# Redefining rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a rails project that was once on heroku. For some reason, I cannot access that rails project on the heroku url anymore. After updating to Rails 3, I decided to get a new URL for the app. How do I go about this?

I have tried the following

```
# in the rails directory...
git remote rm heroku
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

*Error:*

```
! No such app as generated-heroku-subdomain
```

Where `generated-heroku-subdomain` can be replaced by the names generated from any time I ran this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked on the Heroku site under myapps to see if your application is still listed? If it is you'll see a git REPO url at the bottom of the applications page, you can then use this to readd it as a remote URL in your project code.

```
git remote add heroku <url of repo here>
```

Also, check the response of git remote -v to make sure the old application name isn't being referenced.

Comment: I checked my heroku account and I have tons of urls corresponding to every time I have tried this. Still the error message persists

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove your repo and add it again.

```
rm -r .git
git init
git add .
git commit 'master'
heroku create
heroku rename my-new-app
git push heroku master
```

And all should be good.